# hive semantic exception while inserting the data

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, orc, bigdata

I created a hive table with ORC. If I insert data from the hive console it works perfectly.But If I insert data from the Jdbc code.It throws hive semantic exception.

**Error**

> rg.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling  statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_TABLE_OR_COL not supported in insert/values
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:326)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:102)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:171)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:268)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:410)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:397)
>       sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
>       java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
>       com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:258)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:509)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
>       org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
>       org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
>       org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
>       org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My **insert query**

```
result = name+","+age+","+job;
String stmt = "INSERT INTO table real_estate.addressinformation_orc VALUES(" + result + ")";
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the strings. Assuming age is an integer, this will work, but it's a bad solution:

```
result = "'" + name + "'," + age + ",'" + job + "'"
```

It's a bas solution because if name and job countain a quote, that would break your code.
A much better solution is to  use prepared statements. With prepared statements, you don't have to worry about qoting:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.
  prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table " +     
    "real_estate.addressinformation_orc VALUES(?,?,?)");

preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, age);
preparedStatement.setString(3, job);

// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your result variable in string quotes.

For example :
insert into table test1(sno,name)  values (1,jj);

Above line throws error, if we edit the same as below it works

insert into table test1(sno,name)  values (1,"jj");

Here name datatype is string

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You need to quote the string otherwise It will throw the same error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.